# How to make for loop run in parallel in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, for-loop

I've been looking around everywhere for this extremely simple question without any luck. I have the following code:

```
@tf.function
def parTest():
    for i in tf.range(tf.constant(10)):
        insideFunc(0,i)

@tf.function
def insideFunc(x_in,j):
    for i in tf.range(tf.random.uniform([],0,1000,dtype=tf.int32)):
        x_in += tf.cast(i,tf.int32)
    tf.print(j)
return x_in
```

And when I run it it does not run in parallel, even though there's no dependencies between the loop iterations. I've tried running the insideFunc using tf.map_fn and it runs it in parallel (the prints get all mixed up), however tf.map_fn can't handle variable length inputs/outputs so I can't use it :( There has to be a way to build a graph using a loop which runs in parallel.

The original problem I have is simple, I have a list of tensors with different lengths and I need to perform the same operations to the tensors in the list, but since they are of different lengths I need to do this in a loop and for god knows what reason this makes it impossible to do these operations in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Turns our @tf.function messes up parallel execution somehow. Managed to get it to run in parallel with this function:

```
def parTest(v):
y = v
for i in range(5):
    y += insideFunc(v,i)
return y
```

but if I added @tf.function it no longer ran in parallel.